# Intel C++ Compiler Installer not finding Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, intel-parallel-studio

So I was trying to install the Intel C++ Compiler (in the Parallel Studio XE 2018 bundle) and when I go to install it comes up with the warning "Intel C++ Compiler will not work because none of the supported environments is found on your computer," among others. However, one of those supported environments is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, which I have installed.

I read online that there's some issue with the most recent versions of Visual Studio and that the compiler only works with versions 15.6 and below. I have 15.5.6, but of the Community version. I'm not sure if the Professional version is required; if it is I don't have it installed and I can't figure how to install a previous version.

If there is no way to make this work (or there is, but it's too much of a pain), suggestions for other C++ compilers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already have Visual Studio installed, why not just use that?

Comment: Does that have a c++ compiler, and if so how good is it? (not very experienced with this stuff if you can't tell)

Comment: Visual Studio is the traditional C++ compiler (and related tools) for Windows. It's likely that most of the software you're using right now was built in it.

Comment: So I don't actually need Parallel Studio? Thank you!

Comment: I have no way of knowing what you need because you haven't told us what you're trying to do, but that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could see this document about “Troubleshooting Fortran Integration Issues with Microsoft Visual Studio*”：

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/troubleshooting-fortran-integration-issues-with-visual-studio/

It shared the version of Visual Studio that is supported by the Intel Parallel Studio XE now.